# Pb with ActionServer and/or ActionClient in python

Tags: ros2, python, action, ros-humble, action-client

I've got an ActionServer that works when called from the command line, but when I use my own ActionClient, the send_goal command **never ends waiting**. Can someone tell me what's wrong ?

my ActionClient

```
    goal_msg = ApplicantRegistration.Goal()
    goal_msg.action_topic = "/my/action"
    goal_msg.info_topic = "/my/info"

    server_name = "my_serveur"
    client = ActionClient(self, ApplicantRegistration, server_name)
    self.get_logger().info(f"wait for server {server_name}")
    client.wait_for_server(timeout_sec=10.0)

    self.get_logger().info("send goal '%s'" % goal_msg)
    res = client.send_goal(goal_msg)
    # never reached
    self.get_logger().info("send_goal succeed => {res}")
```

And my ActionServer

```
    server_name = "my_serveur"
    self.get_logger().info(f"will start server {server_name}.")
    self.__register_server = ActionServer(
        self, ApplicantRegistration,
        server_name,
        execute_callback=self._action_cb,
    )
    self.get_logger().info(f"server {server_name} started.")

def _action_cb(self, goal_handle):
    self.get_logger().info(f"Goal1: {goal_handle.status}")
    goal_handle.succeed()
    self.get_logger().info(f"Goal2: {goal_handle.status}")
    result = ApplicantRegistration.Result()

    return result
```

ActionServer validated with

```
ros2 action send_goal my_serveur <pkg>/action/ApplicantRegistration '{ action_topic: "/my/action", info_topic: "/my/info" }'
```

---

I try to wait for future after using send_goal_async, not working.
Here is my loop:

```
    # res = client.send_goal(goal_msg)
    # replaced by
    self.get_logger().info(f"send_goal_async")
    future = client.send_goal_async(goal_msg)
    while rclpy.ok():
        if future.done():
            self.get_logger().info(f"future is done -> {future.result()}")
            break
```